# MSN Chatting on browser?

Tags: javascript

Does Microsoft offer any API that displays MSN status (online/offline)? Or a service (iframe based or not) that allows the user to chat with a msn user from the browser?

I've found some stuff by googling but most of it has been deprecated or doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely not. [Microsoft is planning to retire Messenger in favor of Skype](http://www.examiner.com/article/say-good-bye-to-msn-messenger).